# SAPUI5 Deploying from SAP WEB IDE

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, web-ide

We have on-Premise apps deployed through Eclipse to our ABAP repository, with the component-preload file generated using gulp.

Now that we've moved to SAP WEB IDE, which using grunt as opposed to gulp. Can apps be deployed directly to ABAP without eclipse or will it cause conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

we have a similar environment:

- WebIDE Full Stack
- Gulp

I manually deployed an application to our ABAP Repo. **The app works but is not minified.**

If you are dropping Eclipse completely and only use the WebIDE you probably won't need gulp and can replace it with the default grunt stuff generated by the WebIDE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by 'not minified' is the preload file generated by grunt ignored? Will the old gulp files cause conflicts? Will they need to be removed and how?

Comment: If you don't have a Gruntconfig then there will be no preload file. The old gulp files do not cause conflicts. They can be removed if you don't need them anymore.